# Hibernate-Spatial, JPA, Spring, MySQL 5.7 (unable to retrieve Point)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using the frameworks as stated in the topic.

this is my part of my jpa properties in application.yml for spring

```
jpa:
  database: mysql
  hibernate:
    naming:
      physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl 
  properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect
      globally_quoted_identifiers: true
  show-sql: true
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to trigger SpatialDialect for MySQL5.7

My entity's method for Point

```
@Type(type = "com.iheartcity.apiapp.geometry.MySQLGeometryType")
@Column(name = "location", nullable = false)
public Point getLocation() {
    return this.location;
}
public void setLocation(Point location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

I created a class MySQLGeometryType.java:

```
package com.iheartcity.apiapp.geometry;

import org.hibernate.spatial.JTSGeometryType;
import org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLGeometryTypeDescriptor;

public class MySQLGeometryType extends JTSGeometryType {

    public MySQLGeometryType() {
        super(MySQLGeometryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

With the @Type(type = "com.iheartcity.apiapp.geometry.MySQLGeometryType")

it works perfectly. However, when I commented it, I start to get error when running the code to retrieve the data.

Here is the exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2775) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1741) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1667) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1556) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1458) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]
at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar:5.2.2.Final]at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Which Point class in java is that ?

Answer (score 2):

The actual solution is to remove `@Type` and use `@Column(name = "location", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "Point")`

Note that this is for MySQL

Comment: In my case I had to add Hibernate Spatial (`'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.0.12.Final'`) into my project, then in the Java JPA entity, make the `POINT` field to be of type `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point`, and then make its `columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` class and then you don't need to specify the `@Type` explicitly.

Check out this example on the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-types-mapping-example).

Comment: Then it should work without specifying a type. Check out [this test on GitHub](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/spatial/SpatialTest.java).

Comment: @Vlad, highly value your opinion on this forum. But please do check in Hibernate 5. If we don't provide columnDefinition="POINT" it doesn't create a mysql field of type POINT at all. Similiar case with GEOMETRY

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct dialect to the application.properties fixed this error for me:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect
```